# remove all httprequests like get, post, file requests after store in a provided array

Tags: php

is there a way I could delete/destroy/remove all http request like get, post, file requests after I store them unto the array, e.g.

```
$input_arr = [];

foreach( $_GET as $i => $v){
    $input_arr[$i] = $v;
}
```

same to post requests

```
$input_arr = [];

foreach( $_POST as $i => $v){
    $input_arr[$i] = $v;
}
```

and etc. then after stored, destroy/delete/remove all current http requests so they won't be accessible unto my app because simply those requests does not exist anymore. Any help, ideas?

Comment: just for curiousity: is there a particular reason you want/need to do that? Exept not beeing global I don't see a difference between `$_GET` and `$input_arr`

Comment: I'm trying to create an MVC type framework and I just want to make all data accessible inside my framework enviroment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply try [`unset`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php)ing `$_GET` and `$_POST` when you're finished with them:

```
unset($_GET, $_POST);
```

Or, if you need it to not be undefined after you're done, just set it to an empty array:

```
$_GET = [];
$_POST = [];
```

Alternatively, if you just want to rename `$_GET` and `$_POST` to a different name, but retain the contents, there's a much easier way to do this with PHP's array [`clone`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php) function:

```
$input_arr1 = clone $_GET;
$input_arr2 = clone $_POST;
```

This way you don't have to write out a `foreach`.